# The Problem in Change Color Font Icon "svg file"

Tags: html, css, icons, glyphicons

I designed an icon by **Adobe Illustrator** software. I saved that in **SVG** format. But I can not change fill with css and also in font icon (create by [icomoon.io](https://icomoon.io/)) and also in add svg file in html.

Is there any problem with the design?

Designed prototype
https://svgshare.com/i/A8N.svg

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should create Css File:

```
    @font-face {
     font-family: 'icomoon';
     src:  url('https://i.icomoon.io/public/temp/0d5322f2ab/UntitledProject/icomoon.eot?j58a20');
     src:  url('https://i.icomoon.io/public/temp/0d5322f2ab/UntitledProject/icomoon.eot?j58a20#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
           url('https://i.icomoon.io/public/temp/0d5322f2ab/UntitledProject/icomoon.ttf?j58a20') format('truetype'),
           url('https://i.icomoon.io/public/temp/0d5322f2ab/UntitledProject/icomoon.woff?j58a20') format('woff'),
           url('https://i.icomoon.io/public/temp/0d5322f2ab/UntitledProject/icomoon.svg?j58a20#icomoon') format('svg');
     font-weight: normal;
     font-style: normal;
 }

 [class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
     /* use !important to prevent issues with browser extensions that change fonts */
     font-family: 'icomoon' !important;
     speak: none;
     font-style: normal;
     font-weight: normal;
     font-variant: normal;
     text-transform: none;
     line-height: 1;

     /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
     -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
     -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
 }

.icon-A8N:before {
    content: "\e900";
    color: #b90f00;
}
```

Then your HTML will be this like:

```
<link href="~/Content/StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<span class="icon-A8N" style="font-size: 150px;"></span>
```

To change the size of your icon you should use *font-size* property and also you can change the color from CSS.